# How to use vim's mark functionality but keep the cursor where it is

Tags: vim

Vim's [mark functionality](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks) allows one to apply functions to every line between the current line and the marked line. For example if I mark the below line `3` with `k`

```
1 var a = 0;
2 while (a < 10){
3 a++;
4 console.log('Hello');
5 console.log('world');
6 █
7 }
```

and from the cursor position (`█`) issue the command `>'k`, I will get the following

```
1 var a = 0;
2 while (a < 10){
3 █  a++;
4    console.log('Hello');
5    console.log('world');
6
7 }
```

(Note: the cursos might be over the `a`, but that's not important)

This is the desired effect, but now the cursor has moved all the way back up. For most cases this is desirable, as I usually want to edit from the top. But in this case, I might want to indent again, so I have to navigate once again to the bottom. In cases where I am indenting 20+ lines this becomes a real chore.

How can I temporarily disable this seek back function?

Comment: Why don't you put another mark where you are (at the bottom) and jump to it when done? Otherwise, maybe C-o will work.

Comment: @fge yes that occurred to me too, but I was looking for an option rather than a work around.

Comment: +1 for a very well explained question, with the line numbers and cursor mark touch.

Comment: There are so many good answers, I don't know which one to accept

Comment: You could give it some time, and accept the one which you end up using most often. I'm guessing `` is going the be the best general-purpose habitual thing (along with `.`, `;` `,` `@@` and `@:` for repeating commands, gv (restore visual selection), `<C-r>.`, `<C-r>/` for register recall, `'.`, `'>`, `'<` for last insert/visual selections etc )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do <kbd>></kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> just hit <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> (single quote, single quote) - not back tick, I think - and you'll go back to where you were.

If you do this often then you can map a key to do it in one:

```
:map >> >'k''
```

Then whenever you hit <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> it'll do that sequence.

Comment: @puk backticks restore cursor _column_ as well

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to press <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (i.e. back-tick twice) after your command to jump back to the previous location.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of how many times you want to repeat that action.

- If it was 2 or 3 times I would use:

  <kbd>''</kbd> to come back to line 6.
  <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat your last command (indent those lines).
- If it would be more times, I would use a macro `qa` to begin record, `q` to end record and `<number>@a` to repeat it.

Comment: the `.` doesn't work because it repeats the `>'k` command, but now that we are back on the first link (marked as `k`) then only that line will be indented

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean: `>'k` indent lines, `''` comes back to line 6 and `.` re-indent all the lines. Both commands must be repeated. That way it works in my system.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought you meant '.' on it's own, as in ">'k" followed immediately by '.' without the "''"

Answer (score 1):

The most exact answer I can think of is simply:

```
:'k,.>
```

I.e., use a command-mode command with a range ([`:he :range`, and other sections](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_10.html#10.3))

In fact, you'd be able to to do 'remote action stuff' that would resemble levitation illusions to non-vim-initiated programmers. Just try

```
:'k>
```

Indenting a marked line, *from a distance*!<sup>1</sup>

You'll find that most interesting edit commands have a command-mode version. E.g.

```
:'ky|put
```

Yanking the marked line, put it after current cursor line.

If the command-mode command isn't there, there is always `:normal`. E.g. you can

```
:'k,.norm ,cc
```

using NerdCommenter to comment the block instead of indenting

---

Now, for fun:

```
:'k,.>|'k,.retab|'k,.y+|u
```

To take that same block, indent it, retabulate it, put it on the Windows/X clipboard and undo the edit (this is about perfect for pasting on StackOverflow). Note that in practice, I'd prefer to use a visual selection for that:

```
V'k:>|*retab|*y+|u
```

<sup>1</sup>
Fair warning: some 'destructive' commands (such as :delete, or some mappings from scripts, like `:norm ,cc` to comment a selection) actually do move the cursor

Comment: Added some more interest-mongering samples to that simple answer. Vim's command mode is vastly underrated. It was by me, for the first 10 years of using vim :)